# CSS text styling weirdness

Tags: css, types, position, opacity

I'm bringing in text from a caption file and trying to style it in a footer.

Picture example: [Venus image](http://i40.tinypic.com/2v8k7ya.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html laneg="en">
<head>
<title>Sample page</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=100%, height=100%, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#image01_caption_title").load('./captions.html #image01_caption_title');
    jQuery("#image01_artist").load('./captions.html #image01_artist');
    jQuery("#image01_caption").load('./captions.html #image01_caption');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="./image01_large.jpg" width="3485" height="4656" />
<div id="footer"><span id="caption_title"><div id="image01_caption_title"></span></div><span id="caption_artist"><div id="image01_artist"></div></span><span id="caption"><div id="image01_caption"></div></span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
/* BASE SITE STYLE - NOT NEEDED 
---------------------------------------------------- */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie);

/* HTML5 Reset :: style.css
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

html, body, body div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, time, mark, audio, video {
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
outline:0;
font-size:100%;
vertical-align:baseline;
-webkit-user-select: none;
}                                   

@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
#portrait { display: none; }
img {
width:2048px;
height:100%;
}
}

@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
#landscape { display: none; }
img {
width:1536px;
height:100%;
}
}

#header {
position: fixed;
height: 96px;
width: 100%;
background: black;
opacity: 0.5;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}

#caption {
position: fixed;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: normal;
text-align: left;
background: transparent;
color: white;
opacity: 1.0;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: 700px;
}

#caption_title  {
position: fixed;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
background: transparent;
font-size: 36px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
color: white;
opacity: 1.0;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-top: 15px;
}

#caption_client  {
position: fixed;
background: transparent;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: normal;
color: white;
opacity: 1.0;
text-indent: 260px;
margin-top: -34px;
}

#footer {
position: fixed;
height: 164px;
width: 2048px;
background: black;
opacity: 0.5;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

I'm not really understanding why the positioning is behaving the way it is (one caption element seems to be inherited from another), and I can't figure out the opacity. I want the text to be solid white, but it's inheriting 0.5 Opacity from the footer class.

Any help on that or suggestions on optimising the classes would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: In the first, check your html markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't usable (there's no text in the footer), and the question isn't all that clear. Anyhow, opacity is inherited by all child elements, so is generally not good to use. RGBA colors are much more friendly. E.g.

```
#footer {background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
```

That will give the footer background 50% opacity without affecting anything else.

Comment: Thanks, the RGBA code fixed my opacity problem.

The captions come in from captions.html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html laneg="en">
<head>
<title>Captions</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p id="image01_caption_title">Birth of Venus</p>
<p id="image01_artist">&#91;Sandro Botticelli&#93;</p>
<p id="image01_caption">The Birth of Venus is a 1486 painting by Sandro Botticelli. It depicts the goddess Venus, having emerged from the sea as a fully grown woman, arriving at the sea-shore (which is related to the Venus Anadyomene motif).</p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Cool, glad that helped. I realized after my comment that the content was pulled in via JS.